# Does inductance in a resistor matter if it is used as a bleeder resistor?

Tags: high-voltage, high-frequency

I am designing a Marx generator and I want to place a bleeder resistor across each capacitor in every stage of the Marx gen.

I have been looking at using low cost [RI80 resistors from eBay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/325244197085?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110013%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.SIMRXI%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20201210111452%26meid%3D3703122090b449ed9db4827a775838bc%26pid%3D101196%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D233964054875%26itm%3D325244197085%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D4429486%26algv%3DPromotedRVIPbooster%26brand%3DBrand&_trksid=p4429486.c101196.m2219&amdata=cksum%3A3252441970853703122090b449ed9db4827a775838bc%7Cenc%3AAQAIAAAA8JsbtOKd5uIU0OgsJNCgXCOCBt8%252FRVdpIC%252F1VLRCPDTII56TukPdiGcVoTM068cfhVFw8JBnJ4aExU3cTpY3WLXwNtK6jVNUZKG76LO5y21osKdtvBuh7X0HnYlzm9jm2o%252FKb5yUMzzF8NL9jhiO0BSBBNIqgOsZItskac52uSJGHVCc4f8q0zHjd2hAiX5iHuuIPpOVr1oUvov1vPXLEipoTaKahlCqMSMzkI7dvNu2zRs5dk0yyVxvJV9VMUj%252FcATXzPAjNqeEs3cCeX6fDf0YgVRUy1Yhz%252FzCFGr5Y9uN7H%252B9fYckWdPUWoBxPVbFfQ%253D%253D%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A4429486). Each stage of the Marx will be charged by a 45kV power supply so I was thinking of using five or six RI80 10kV 3W 200MOhm resistors in series for each stage.

I have run into conflicting data that RI80 resistors are wirewound or some kind of glass glaze film resistors. I know wirewound resistors have a large inductance. If they are wirewound does the high inductance matter if they are being placed across a capacitor and used as bleeder resistors?

Comment: Please supply a PDF data sheet for the resistors you linked.

Comment: Note with 5 or 6 resistors in series, if any one fails open or if you lose a connection along the string, you've lost your bleed path.  If this is a product where safety is a concern, you should consider using resistors in a parallel/series arrangement.

Comment: @Andy thank you for the suggestion, it did not occur to me to search for datasheet. It says it uses film and a zigzag pattern to eliminate any inductance.
https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/download/1016863/TOKEN/RI80.html

Comment: @SteveSH it is for a hobby project its not being sold or anything. If it was I wouldn't mind making my Marx stages larger and would be able to fit in more components like a parallel bleeder resistor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parasitic inductance is not really an issue for bleeder resistors. Wire-wound resistors should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, good to know regardless if it has high or low inductance that it should work.